# I can no longer open my Xcode project anymore, not even on AppCode

Tags: xcode

If I just open up my `.xcworkspace` Xcode will give me the spinning wheel of death. If I open up my `.xcodeproj` instead, then Xcode will not even open up the main Window.

This problem all started this morning, I tried opening my Xcode project and it caused Xcode to crash immediately, so I wiped my derived data, and I was still getting the same crash issue.

I then reinstalled Xcode, then finally, Xcode would no longer attempt to reopen the previously open windows.

So I then installed the latest version of AppCode, and even app code won't work, when I try to build and run my app in AppCode, AppCode will do the "Build Process" forever and never complete...

Is this a cocoa pods issue or something???

Comment: Sad that today, this many years later, I am having the exact same problem.